# ABP Framework 4.4.3 Package IdentityServer4 4.1.1 is not compatible with net50 on Deployment

Tags: abp

I am using ABP framework 4.4.3.
Project successfully running via Visual Studio 2019. However While deploying Nuget restore throwing Error:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package IdentityServer4 4.1.1 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package IdentityServer4 4.1.1 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
```

The error is clear. But the issue is that ABP is using its package for Identity management, which I can not downgrade to ver 3 of dotnet core.

Stuck and need help

Answer (score 3):

You may be using some additional parameters for restoring package that checks consistency between packages while restoration.

[IdentityServer4 4.1.1 works fine on .Net5](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/5157#issuecomment-778414302).

You can also create an issue at https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues with providing steps to reproduce or a public repo.

Comment: HI . I was using Azure **Classic Editor** for pipeline . Now tried using YAML and went successful

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but came across to it while trying to update a DevOps pipeline (classic). Even trying locally the nuget command was failing.

The solution in our case was to upgrade the nuget version from 4.9.6 to 5.x (5.11.5.1).
You can download it from here:

https://www.nuget.org/downloads

So, either add a task to your pipeline to force update the nuget.exe or use your own version from the source code (after dowloading and upgrading it locally).